# Can an app (Android,iOS,Windows) ask the user for permission, before downloading, to read and store their browsing history?

Tags: android, ios, google-chrome, windows-phone-7, browser-history

Can an app (Android,iOS,Windows) ask the user for permission, before downloading, to read and store their browsing history in a server.(Ex in:Chrome, Safari,Firefox,Opera,Dolphin, Etc.)? If so, what are the permissions? 
I have not worked on any code just want to see if it's possible by knowing if the permissions exist. I saw Android has READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS.

Comment: On Android, there is no more centralized browsing history. The permission you cite is obsolete. Each browser may have an API that you can try to use to access this information, though some will not.

Comment: iOS has no such feature.

Comment: @CommonsWare Do you think that an extension in the browser would allow for the reading of browser history to then be sent to the app?

Comment: Possibly, for those few mobile browsers that support extensions. And, again, the details will be specific to each browser.

Comment: @CommonsWare in that case i should develop the app and browser extension for each specific browser for this to be possible. Thank you for the input!